# Space not work between option tag words in Safari and Chrome browser

Tags: css, browser, safari, cross-browser

Html code

```
    <select class="embroidery_options" name="personalise_this[embroidery_logo_location1]">
    <option value="">-----Select Position-----
    </option><option disabled="" value="">----------TOPS-----------</option>
    <option value="Left chest">Left       £1.75</option>
    <option value="Right chest">Right     £1.75</option>
    <option value="Centre chest">Centre   £1.75</option>                        
    </select>
```

Css code:(i have used below font in css code that's work only Firefox and IE browser )

```
.logo_placement select option{font-family:Menlo, Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace, serif;}
```

that font is work Firefox and IE but not working in Safari and Chrome browser

Image from Firefox and IE browser

[image]

Image from Safari and Chrome browser

[image]

**[CHECK DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aKy8L/1/)**

Comment: have you tried `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: yes i have tried please check demo here and compare all browser http://jsfiddle.net/aKy8L/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a monospace font, but for both the select and the option. 
Try removing all your font definitions and simply choose Courier

```
.logo_placement select option , .logo_placement select {
    font-family:Courier;
}
```

check it here http://jsfiddle.net/EgDRS/.
Its working in my  chrome, opera, ie and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply use a monospace (or fixed-width) font. You have specified too many font options some of which are for Firefox and others for Safari. Try removing all your font definitions and simply choose Courier and that should work in all browsers.

Comment: I have tried Courier font also but not working safari and Chrome browser, see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/aKy8L/3/

Comment: Actually, I was wrong sorry. You apparently cannot style a select cross-browser. See [CSS Tricks for more info](http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/)